# React context and Reducer doesn't work as expected in webpack dev environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-context, esbuild

Summary: React component is not getting context new state after first update in development environment only.

I have a private npm react component built with esbuild. I am using this component in React/Nextjs applications. in the component's source code, I am using React context and one of the components is subscribing to the context as follows:

```
export default function Filters(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(myStore);
  const { filters } = state; // filters are updated only the first time and the rest of the time filters are always the same. 
  // 
  // ...rest of the component
```

When developing this component in its own repo, the code runs as expected. also when this component is used with nextjs in production environment, it works as expected. but the problem does exist in development environment only.

I tried to update the source code of the library and add some logs and the state is beign push as expected from React reducer as follows:

```
case "UPDATE_FILTERS": {
      const oldFilters = state.search.filters[action.data.type] || [];
      const searchIndex = oldFilters?.indexOf(action.data.value);
      if (searchIndex >= 0) {
        oldFilters.splice(searchIndex);
      } else {
        oldFilters.push(action.data.value);
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        aggregateJobs: false,
        performInitialSearch: true,
        search: {
          ...state.search,
          filters: {
            ...state.search.filters,
            [action.data.type]: [...oldFilters], // this value is correct here and has the expected filters but the component is not getting the new value after first use. but in production, it works as expected.
          },
        },
      };
    }
```

does webpack do something behind the scene which cause a component to get a cached value after first time?

Note: I tried the component with a fresh react app created with `create-react-app` and I noteced the same

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still have no answer to this question